# Use different WordPress themes based on category

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to display a different theme based on whatever category you're in?

For example:

```
blog.example.com/category/foo -> style1.
blog.example.com/category/bar -> style2.
```

A Google search brought up [this page](http://mattmedia.net/2007/10/09/how-to-set-up-custom-wordpress-category-templates-in-four-easy-steps/), and he recommends doing this in single.php:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category(5) ) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/style1.php');
} else {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/style2.php');
}
```

Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using `include` for this. Wordpress has an amazing [`get_template_part`](http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/) function just for these situations. It has a built-in fallback mechanism, and integrates nicely with your theme:

```
$categories = get_the_category();

get_template_part('for-category', $categories[0]->slug);
```

Then, just name your files with the category slug:

> blog.example.com/category/foo -> for-category-foo.php
>   blog.example.com/category/bar -> for-category-bar.php

Remember to also have a default `for-category.php` file, so that you can fallback to that if you don't have a custom file for the current category.

Comment: @dallen - Sure. Note that the article you linked to is from way back in 2007, before Wordpress introduced the `get_template_part` function. While `get_template_part` isn't all that new, the article I linked to is hot off the presses (this morning). Definitely worth a read.